# Access variables from class to class

Tags: java

How do i access some variables from another class? For example, i have 2 files:

**Main.java**

```
package keyboardgame;

import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Main extends Applet implements KeyListener
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static boolean keyboardRightPressed = false;
    private static boolean keyboardLeftPressed = false;
    private static boolean keyboardUpPressed = false;
    private static boolean keyboardDownPressed = false;

    int ballX = 20; 
    int ballY = 20;
    int ballSpeed = 10;

    public void init()
    {
        addKeyListener(this);
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) 
    {
        int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
        {
            keyboardRightPressed = true;
            ballX = ballX + ballSpeed;
            repaint();
        }

        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
        {
            keyboardLeftPressed = true;
            ballX = ballX - ballSpeed;
            repaint();
        }

        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
        {
            keyboardUpPressed = true;
            ballY = ballY - ballSpeed;
            repaint();
        }

        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
        {
            keyboardDownPressed = true;
            ballY = ballY + ballSpeed;
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) 
    {
        int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
        {
            keyboardRightPressed = false;
            repaint();
        }

        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
        {
            keyboardLeftPressed = false;
            repaint();
        }

        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
        {
            keyboardUpPressed = false;
            repaint();
        }

        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
        {
            keyboardDownPressed = false;
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }


    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        g.fillOval(ballX,ballY,20,20);
        g.drawString("Right :"+keyboardRightPressed,0,10);
        g.drawString("Left :"+keyboardLeftPressed,0,20);
        g.drawString("Up :"+keyboardUpPressed,0,30);
        g.drawString("Down :"+keyboardDownPressed,0,40);        
    }

}
```

**KeyThread.java**

```
package keyboardgame;

public class KeyThread implements Runnable
{

    public KeyThread(String s,int speed)
    {
        name = s;
        time = speed;
    }

    public void run() 
    {
        try
        {
            if(keyboardRightPressed == true)
            {
                ballX = ballX + 10; 
                ballY = ballY + 10;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

What do i want is that from **KeyThread.java** to be able to modify/increment/access values from **Main.java** especially

```
int ballX = 20; 
int ballY = 20;
```

so i can call my thread from **Main.java** like

```
Thread t5 = new Thread(new KeyThread("Moving Right", ballX = ballX + 1, 20));
t5.start();
```

How can i do that?
And why is it so hard to do it?

Comment: Since you are new to JAVA, as said by you in some comments, why don't you try JApplet, instead of Applet from javax.swing package. That is much better compared to Applet from java.awt package. Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare your variables `public` instead of `private`, you can refer to them as (for example) `Main.ballX`, but this is generally a bad practice.  We organize things into classes to keep separate things separate; if we start using the members of class A within class B, then class B has a dependency on A that can make it hard to debug and maintain later on.  Better would be to provide a "getter" or "accessor" method inside Main (eg `getBallX()` and `setBallX(int x)`) which give the owning class (in this case, Main) better control over its private members.

Comment: i write Main. and "ballX" don't appear (using Eclipse) so it must be something wrong ... , so for my problem what is the recommended approach? i didn't quite understand it like clear water

Answer (score 2):

In order to invoke non-static methods of an object, you need an instance of the class. For more information, see [Objects](http://www.iismarconi.net/inside/materiale/java/tutorial/java/javaOO/objects.html).

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding this ... but i have to. I come from a PHP/HTML type of programming witch it's easy and i'm trying to fit in with java. Hopefully i will make it :))

Comment: @RowMinds, Ah...an OOP newbie. Well, I suggest you start [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/index.html). G'luck!

Comment: Hey, it's not that bad, i actually made a ball move in a form on full screen from keyboard :) i just don't understand some concepts, sorry ...

Answer (score 1):

Also, adding to the other answers, if a frequent task is going to be adding/subtracting to the value as it appears to be then perhaps a method such as adjustBallX(int x) would be valuable so you can increment/decrement the value without calling get() and set() every time.